# VAD speech databases

Tags: speech-recognition, speech

Does anybody know any open voice/speech annotated database for Voice Activity Detection? Or any other corpus for speech evaluation purposes?

The ones I know are private: AURORA, TIMIT, SpeechDat-Car, Speecon, Catalan Speecon.

The other option is to create hand-labeled annotations for own recordings, or use a method like the Short-Term Energy Contour. But in the first case the amount of files to process would be insurmountable, and in the second, the energy based methods only work fine for free-noise recordings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take some big speech corpus like TEDLIUM and add the noise you like:

http://www-lium.univ-lemans.fr/en/content/ted-lium-corpus

The advantage of TEDLIUM is that it's a set of continuous recordings with speech timings, not just a collection of utterances.

Comment: Wow thanks. I heard also that [The IViE Corpus](http://www.phon.ox.ac.uk/files/apps/old_IViE/index.html) is also a good choice, but is not as timed as the one you suggested.

Answer (score 7):

Researchers from the Johns Hopkins University have recently released a corpus of music, speech, and noise which, according to them, is suitable for training models for voice activity detection and music/speech discrimination.

See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.08484.pdf for details.

Answer (score 3):

Free VAD Data set recorded in real environment with ground truth label:

refer: https://github.com/jtkim-kaist/VAD-Toolkit

Comment: Kaist has been earning a good reputation these years. Is this toolkit related to the work of  Yang-Hann Kim? I wonder because I took his MOOC in Acoustics.